# Get the list of RGB pixel values of each superpixel

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, scikit-image, superpixels

l have an RGB image of dimension (224,224,3). l applied superpixel segmentation on it using SLIC algorithm.

As follow :

```
img= skimageIO.imread("first_image.jpeg")
print('img shape', img.shape) # (224,224,3)
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=1000, compactness=0.01, sigma=1) # Up to 1000 segments
segments_slic.shape
(224,224)
```

Number of returned segments are :

```
np.max(segments_slic)
Out[49]: 595
```

From 0 to 595. So, we have 596 superpixels (regions).

Let's take a look at `segments_slic[0]`

```
segments_slic[0]
Out[51]: 
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
        3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
        5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,
        8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
       10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12,
       12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14,
       14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16,
       16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18,
       18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20,
       20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
       21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
       23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25,
       25, 25, 25])
```

What l would like to get ?

for each superpixel region make two arrays as follow:

1) Array  : contain the indexes of the pixels belonging to the same superpixel.

For instance

`superpixel_list[0]` contains all the indexes of the pixels belonging to superpixel 0 .

`superpixel_list[400]` contains all the indexes of the pixels belonging to superpixel 400

2)superpixel_pixel_values[0] : contains the pixel values (in **RGB**) of the pixels belonging to superpixel 0.

For instance, let's say that pixels 0, 24 , 29, 53  belongs to the superpixel 0. Then we get

```
superpixel[0]= [[223,118,33],[245,222,198],[98,17,255],[255,255,0]]# RGB values of pixels belonging to superpixel 0
```

What is the efficient/optimized way to do that ? (Because l have l dataset of images to loop over)

**EDIT-1**

```
def sp_idx(s, index = True):
     u = np.unique(s)
         if index:
     return [np.where(s == i) for i in u]
         else:
     return [s[s == i] for i in u]
     #return [s[np.where(s == i)] for i in u] gives the same but is slower
superpixel_list = sp_idx(segments_slic)
superpixel      = sp_idx(segments_slic, index = False)
```

In `superpixel_list`  we are supposed to get a list containing the index of pixels belonging to the same superpixel.
For instance
`superpixel_list[0]` is supposed to get all the pixel indexes of the pixel affected to superpixel 0

however l get the following :

```
superpixel_list[0]
Out[73]: 
(array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
         3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,
         5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,
         7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10,
        10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1,
        2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Why two arrays ?

In superpixel[0] for instance we are supposed to get the RGB pixel values of each pixel affected to supepixel 0 as follow :
for instance pixels 0, 24 , 29, 53 are affected to superpixel 0 then :

```
superpixel[0]= [[223,118,33],[245,222,198],[98,17,255],[255,255,0]]
```

However when l use your function l get the following :

```
superpixel[0]
Out[79]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is what regionprops are designed to calculate.  See `skimage.measure.regionprops`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using `np.where` and the resulting indices.

```
def sp_idx(s, index = True):
     u = np.unique(s)
     return [np.where(s == i) for i in u]

superpixel_list = sp_idx(segments_slic)
superpixel      = [img[idx] for idx in superpixel_list]
```

Comment: why we get two arrays for each superpixel_list ?

Comment: Because every pixel has two indices, since the array is two dimensional.  The output format of `np.where` can directly index the original array (like `s[idx]`), whereas something like `np.c_[np.where(s == i)].T` (which looks nicer) isn't as functional.

Comment: l think it makes sense. Do you mean, it represents (x,y) coordinates of each pixel. the first array represents x coordinates and the second array the y coordinates ? do you confirm this !

Comment: . . . yes?  Try looking up the documentation of [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)